V3 AWS S3 JavaScript SDK on deleteObjectCommand gets 204 but doesn't delete object
So my question is similar to this other one:
V3 AWS S3 JavaScript SDK on deleteObjectCommand 204 response code
... I get the same answer:
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 204,
    requestId: 'WK2PAFG132EBSCB5',
    extendedRequestId: 'tx6+bepnRyJxR3UfurfLAjRDtIiu17Q5UlerzkNFE54NpXXsdgkmFhLHSsN8tQlgTQZonQnSa5Y=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  }
}

But when I go check in my bucket, the file is still there. If I run a ListObjectsV2Command, the file is listed, as if no delete command happened. Being patient doesn't seem to help, the file doesn't disappear.
Code is as simple as it gets:
const command = new s3client.DeleteObjectCommand({
  Bucket: MY_S3BUCKET,
  Key: path,
});
const response = await client.send(command)
console.log(response);

And my other operations, like getSignedUrl or ListObjectsV2Command are working fine. I thought about policy issues, but I did my best to give all powers to this user on this bucket. Also, I would expect a decent error message if policy were an issue, like 401 "not authorized".
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'd guess that you are not deleting the object you think you're deleting. Make sure that path does not have a leading forward slash.

Gee, I can't believe it. Thanks, I was getting crazy, I checked the key a million times, and somehow missed that obvious '/'.

You'll get a 204 No Content response when deleting an S3 object if you have the necessary permission and the object was deleted. However, you'll also get the same response if you have the necessary permission and the object does not exist. So, in a sense, the DeleteObject API simply ensures that the object no longer exists.
Unrelated, it's quite common for S3 users to create S3 object keys from a corresponding Unix or MacOS OS file system path which looks like /folder1/folder2/file.pdf and begins with a /. S3 object keys, however, look like folder1/folder2/file.pdf and do not begin with a /.
So, I think you're attempting to delete the wrong key. Specifically the key you're deleting begins with an errant / and that operation succeeds and returns 204, but doesn't actually delete anything.

This is a strange design from AWS. I would expect a 404 or some other indication that the key does not exist.

@Pedro deleting an object is an idempotent operation. That's valuable in a distributed system.

I see, that makes sense now. It seems we’ve had a silent issue with our delete calls for months due to an incorrect key being passed. I suppose the only reliable way to verify successful deletion would be to first check that the object exists (to confirm the key is correct), and then verify after the delete call that it’s actually been removed.

Yes, you could do that via HeadObject before DeleteObject, but you wouldn't have to check after DeleteObject because if the DeleteObject API call succeeds then that's proof that the object no longer exists.
